# How to make a shape move with keyIsDown (p5.js)

Tags: javascript, p5.js

So I'm trying to make a shape move in the canvas with p5.js. However, all it does is redrawing the same shape in the newly assigned position without deleting the shape in the old position, leaving sort of a trail, and not completely moving it like I wanted. [You can see the result here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wg1R4.png)

Below is the code for my "Player" class (the shape that I want to move):

```
function Player() {
    this.hp = 10;
    this.x = 230;
    this.y = 240;
    this.color = "red";
    this.r = 10;

    this.spawn = function(){
        fill(this.color);
        noStroke();
        rect(this.x, this.y, this.r*2, this.r*2);
    }
}
```

This is my code in the *setup* and *draw* functions in p5.js:

```
var p1;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 500);
    background("green");
    p1 = new Player();;
}

function draw() {
    p1.spawn();
    if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) { 
        p1.x--;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)) {
        p1.x++;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)) {
        p1.y--;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW)) {
        p1.y++;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: place `background("green");` inside `draw` function.

Comment: It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear out old frames using the `background()` function. You should generally call `background()` from the first line in the `draw()` function. Here's an example:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(200, 200);
}

function draw() {
  background(64);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 25, 25);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Try moving the call to the `background()` function to the `setup()` function to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

you just use

```
if (keyDown(the key you want to use)) {
 
}
```

or

```
if(keyDown("the key you want to use")){


}
```

Comment: i see that you may be making a game so here is how to do a walk and run feature

Comment: if(keyDown("D") && keyDown("SHIFT")){
    player.x=player.x+5;
}

Comment: here is the walk if(keyDown("D")){
    player.x=player.x+1;
}

Comment: let us know for updates dude

Comment: I did not read the whole question add a background like this background("the color you want")